# pass a url string as parameter to mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to pass a full website url to my controller action, like this:

```
http://myweb/controller/action/http://blabla.com/dir2
```

how to create a new route for passing this parameter to action?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
routes.MapRoute("Name", "{controller}/{action}/{*url}");
```

Additional Info:

- [ASP.NET MVC In-Depth: The Life of an ASP.NET MVC Request](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/03/18/asp-net-mvc-in-depth-the-life-of-an-asp-net-mvc-request.aspx)

Comment: thanks, but with {*url} , I cannot still pass the "http://" for the parameter, HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request. is raised. or with :portnumber at the end of url, same error

Comment: try this <a href="./controller/action/<%= HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://www.riaguy.com") =%>">Test</a>

Comment: thats right, but the parameter is passed from outside of application, I want it to be like restful api which add this url to db, wonder if it is possible to have this format just by typing(without using any server side or client side decode functions) or not

Comment: The problem is not in {*url}, ASP.NET MVC chast can't accept http:// in URL which wasn't encoded.. you can try overcome this by writing custom Route programmatically..

Comment: public class YouCustomRoute : RouteBase { ... }

Comment: also take a look at this article: http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/03/18/asp-net-mvc-in-depth-the-life-of-an-asp-net-mvc-request.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Pass it as a parameter.

```
<%= Html.ActionLink( "Link", 
                     "MyAction",
                     "MyController",
                     new { url = "http://blah.com/blah" },
                     null ) %>
```

Should produce a link that looks like:

```
<a href='/MyController/MyAction?url=http://blah.com/blah'>Link</a>
```

Your action would look like:

```
public ActionResult MyAction( string url )
{
   ...
}
```