# Cannot pass url as a redirect parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, routes

I want to redirect to following action method:

```
public ActionResult Display(string myUrl)
{
    ViewBag.MyUrl = myUrl;
    return View();
}
```

If I try the following code:

```
public ActionResult AnotherActionInTheSameController(string myUrl)
{
    // ... 
    return RedirectToAction("Display", new { myUrl = "domain.com" });
}
```

It would generate the following redirect link:

```
`hostName/ControllerName/Display/domain.com`
```

But the `domain.com` parameter is not passed to `myUrl` parameter...

If I try the following url, then it would hit the desired action:

```
`hostName/ControllerName/Display/?myUrl=domain.com`
```

This is my route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "test",
    url: "{controller}/Display/{myUrl}",
            defaults: new { controller = "MyController", action = "Display", myUrl = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

---

I have tried the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717427/pass-a-url-string-as-parameter-to-mvc-controller) question (adding * to the route) but did not work.

Comment: Your route is wrong. Remove myUrl from route it will work fine.

Comment: Very well. I will move my comment to Answer. Please, accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I'm seeing here is you want to pass the url value as query string myUrl. You do not need to mention query string as part url in your route.

Please remove `{myUrl}` from the route as below. Then things will work fine.

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "test",
url: "{controller}/Display",
        defaults: new { controller = "MyController", action = "Display" }
 );
```